# GMB Business Merger - How should we handle naming conventions?

Tags: seo, local-seo, google-business

I have a client with 6 locations that is merging with another business.

What is the best practice for updating the name on their Google Business Profiles in this situation?

Our fear is that users will not see the listings if they search for the previous business name if we immediately update the profiles to the new name on the merger date.

Could we use a naming convention like [New Busines Name] (Formely [Old Busines Name]) for an extended period of would that not fly?

Comment: Hay Alan - Suggest a name change in Google 1st using "Suggest an edit". if that reflects in your GMB account, that means Google is ready to change it. 

make sure you Update all NAP in other listings also (if you have any), like Bing, Yellow pages... that will help G find the updated name of the business.